# Download files from FTP folder using Loop

Tags: r, loops, download, ftp

I am trying to download all the files inside FTP folder

```
temp <- tempfile()
destination <- "D:/test"

url <- "ftp://XX.XX.net/"
userpwd <- "USER:Password"
filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd = userpwd,ftp.use.epsv = FALSE,dirlistonly = TRUE)     
filenames <- strsplit(filenames, "\r*\n")[[1]]
```

When I am printing "filenames" I am getting all the file names which are inside the FTP folder -  correct output till here

```
[1] "2018-08-28-00.gz" "2018-08-28-01.gz"
[3] "2018-08-28-02.gz" "2018-08-28-03.gz"
[5] "2018-08-28-04.gz" "2018-08-28-05.gz"
[7] "2018-08-28-08.gz" "2018-08-28-09.gz"
[9] "2018-08-28-10.gz" "2018-08-28-11.gz"
[11] "2018-08-28-12.gz" "2018-08-28-13.gz"
[13] "2018-08-28-14.gz" "2018-08-28-15.gz"
[15] "2018-08-28-16.gz" "2018-08-28-17.gz"
[17] "2018-08-28-18.gz" "2018-08-28-23.gz"

for ( i in filenames ) {
    download.file(paste0(url,i), paste0(destination,i), mode="w")    
}
```

I got this error

```
  trying URL 'ftp://XXX.net/2018-08-28-00.gz'
  Error in download.file(paste0(url, i), paste0(destination, i), mode = "w") : 
    cannot open URL 'ftp://XXX.net/2018-08-28-00.gz'
  In addition: Warning message:
  In download.file(paste0(url, i), paste0(destination, i), mode = "w") :
    InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The login request was denied'
```

I modified the code to

```
 for ( i in filenames )
 {
   #download.file(paste0(url,i), paste0(destination,i), mode="w")

 download.file(getURL(paste(url,filenames[i],sep=""), userpwd = 
 "USER:PASSWORD"), paste0(destination,i), mode="w")

}
```

After that, I got this error

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : RETR response: 550
```

Comment: Is `download.file( URL , temp , mode="wb" ) ` is right command for it?

Comment: If you're going to use a `for` loop, you need to use the `i` to subset whatever you're trying to iterate over. Also, the second parameter of `download.file` is `destfile`, which should be the full path to the file to be written, not just a directory.

Comment: Please review the modified code

Answer (score 0):

Without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it is a challenge to directly replicate your problem. Assuming the file names don't include the URL, you'll need to combine them to access the files.

`download.file()` requires a file to be read, an output file, as well as additional flags regarding whether you want a binary download or not.

For example, I have data from Alberto Barradas' Pokémon Stats kaggle.com data set stored on my Github site. To download some of the files to the `test` subdirectory of my R Working Directory, I can use the following code:

```
filenames <- c("gen01.csv","gen02.csv","gen03.csv")
fileLocation <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/"
# use ./ for subdirectory of current directory, end with / to work with paste0()
destination <- "./test/"
# note that these are character files, so use mode="w" 
for (i in filenames){
     download.file(paste0(fileLocation,i),
                          paste0(destination,i),
                          mode="w")

}
```

...and the output:
[image]

The `paste0()` function concatenates text without spaces, which allows the code to generate a fully qualified path name for the url of each source file, as well as the subdirectory where the destination file will be stored.

To illustrate what's happening with `paste0()` in the `for()` loop, we can use `message()` to print to the R console.

```
> # illustrate what paste0() does
> for (i in filenames){
+      message(paste("Source is: ",paste0(fileLocation,i)))
+      message(paste("Destination is:",paste0(destination,i)))
+ }
Source is:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/gen01.csv
Destination is: ./test/gen01.csv
Source is:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/gen02.csv
Destination is: ./test/gen02.csv
Source is:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/gen03.csv
Destination is: ./test/gen03.csv
>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Len Greski for your time. I have modified the code for better understanding, but still getting the error.

Comment: @Bond - The error message is an authentication failure. You'll need to use a download method that supports a userid and password, such as `libcurl`, and then you'll need to configure the correct options for userid and password.